# How can I switch graphics (Intel integrated/ ATI discreet) in 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Lenovo system with an onboard Intel graphics and an ATI Radeon display controller. I was wondering how I could switch to the ATI display or make it my VGA controller, since it seems not to be used at all by the AMDGPU (using kernel 4.4.8).

E.g. my HDMI port is connected to ATI (I assume) so I can't use it, i.e. nothing happens when I connect my TV to it.

How can I switch between the graphics? In 14.04 LTS I had ATI catalyst which made it pretty easy.

My outputs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)

04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev ff)
```

In use:

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Is the open-source driver AMDPGU in use at all? Installed? Disabled?

There's nothing in the additional drivers TAB.

The fglrx web site states:

> ttps://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/fglrx-installer is
>   states there There is no current release of this source package in The
>   Xenial Xerus. You can still report bugs, make translations, and so on,
>   but they might not be used until the package is published.

Any help would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is to switch from "Switchable graphics" to "Use UMA graphics" in Lenovo BIOS. This disables RADEON, and makes the system use only the power-saving GPU, and the battery life has increased, the system works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did the changes by hardware, in the BIOS.

[image]

[image]